# Not able to delete value from a table that is associated with another with foreignkeyconstraint

Tags: ado.net, dataset, constraints

Hi I have two table `Customer` and `Orders`.
`Customer Id` is `primary` in `Customer` and `Foreign key` in `Orders`.
I have done the following coding:

```
ForeignKeyConstraint custOrderFK = new ForeignKeyConstraint("CustOrderFK",
  custDS.Tables["CustTable"].Columns["CustomerID"], 
  custDS.Tables["OrdersTable"].Columns["CustomerID"]);
custOrderFK.DeleteRule = Rule.None;  

custDS.Tables["OrdersTable"].Constraints.Add(custOrderFK);
```

Since I have mentioned `custOrderFK.DeleteRule = Rule.None;` deleting an entry in customer's table should not affect order's table. But I am not able to delete a row from Customer table. It throws exception. I am new to ado.net.
Maybe something is wrong with my understanding of rules.

Answer (score 0):

Use delete cascade option with foreign key.

Comment: But I don't want to delete the value in second table. That's why I have it as None. Is it not possible? Can you explain the concept.

Comment: use on delete set null, so whenever you delete any rows with dependency with foreign key on another table, it will set value as null on delete from main table. You can alter the table to having this in place.

Comment: Sorry! But I could not understand a single thing. Rule.SetNull is a different value altogether which sets null to child items. How is it mixing up here??